# c# - SMTP Async - callback in web service to client page

Tags: c#, email, service, callback, smtp

I had a web service to send email in C#

```
    [WebMethod]
    public string sendEmail()
    {
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        SmtpClient smtpsvr = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");

        // mail settings

        // smtpsvr settings

        smtpsvr.SendCompleted += new SendCompletedEventHandler(sentCompleteCallBack);

        try
        {
            smtpsvr.SendAsync(mail, "Email 1");
            return "sent"; //this return only indicate email has been sent out
        }

        catch (Exception)
        {
            return "failed";
        }
    }

    private void sentCompleteCallBack(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error != null) //error
        {
            sendResult = "email failed " + (string)e.UserState;
        }
        else
        {   //this result, indicate the process of sending email has been completed
            sendResult = "email sent " + (string)e.UserState;
        }

        // ??? haw to pass sendResult value to client page
    }
```

I tried using properties string, class string to get sendResult value; but at the end in client page (aspx), only got empty/null. I only can get string sendEmail() value.

How to pass back the sendResult value to client ?
Thanks so much for the help !

/**********************/
edited

May be I have to change the code like this ? (still using sendAsync()

```
    [WebMethod]
    public string sendEmail()
    {
    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
    SmtpClient smtpsvr = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");

    //mail settings

    //smtpsvr settings
    smtpsvr.SendCompleted += new SendCompletedEventHandler(sentCompleteCallBack);

    try
    {
        smtpsvr.SendAsync(mail, "email 1");
        return "sent"; 
    }

    catch (Exception)
    {
        return "failed";
    }
}

 private void sentCompleteCallBack(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
 {
    if (e.Error != null) //error
    {
       //write to DB_email_status = "failed"
    }
    else
    {   
      //write to DB_email_status = "success"
    }
}
```

in client side page (aspx) :
(1) call web service to send email.
(2) get email sent string value from sendEmail() method.
(3) button_onclick : view/get data from DB_email_status. 
(???) is this case achieveable ?
(!!!) Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using stateless protocol as in HTTP , then the server(Web service) can give only one response to the client. So, there is no way for the WebService to send details of the Async results to the client unless the client probes it again for status.

IMO, your best bet is to use .Send() instead of .SendAsync(). You can use [Timeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.timeout.aspx) property to prevent the method from hanging.

Comment: Thanks Anthony for your reply. So i think, i have to re-design the code using send() but need to wait the process, or using sendAsync() but write the result to database (?). Please see my next post. Thanks

Comment: oopsss..sorry, I mean, Please see in my edited Question, Thanks again.

Comment: Yes that would work. There is also another way out. <br/>
Instead of creating an async call from the webservice, you can create an async call from client that would wait until it gets final response (.send())from webserive. A raw pseudo-code would look like this <br/> `client: { 1)start an async thread and map to another function 2) make call to server } server : { 1)send mail using .send() and pass results back to the waiting client}` . That helps??

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you just pass in a bool as return value in your SendEmail method like below

```
bool sentEmail()
{
bool isValid = false;

try
{
    //if email successful
    isValid = true
}
catch(Exception ex)

{

  //Email Fails
  isValid = false;
}

return isValid;

}
```

Comment: Thanks Tammy for your reply, yupe, it can return as bool/string/int from sendEmail().
but that return value only indicated email has been sent.
what I need is the result value after email sending has been completed, which I think, correct me if i wrong, only can be achieved from smtp.sendCompleted event handler.
Now the problem is how to get the value within that event handler ?
(the value can be string/bool/int/...)
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

or using send() and thread.

```
 [WebMethod]
 public bool sendEmail()
 {
   //mail settings
   //smtp settings
   try 
   { 
        smtp.Send(mail);
        return true;
   }
   catch
   {
       return false;
   }
```

client page (aspx)

```
   private void send()
   {
      Thread.Sleep(100;
      //call web service: sendEmail()
      if true 
      { label.Text = "sent"} else {label.Text = "fail"}
   }

   private void button_Onclick(...)
   {
       Thread t = new Thread (send);
        t.Start();
        t.Join();
    }
```

will behave similiar like sendAsync(), but easier to get return value.